# How to use canvas image as embed image, discord js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, canvas, discord.js

I'm trying to use a canvas image for my message using this guide:
https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/canvas.html#setting-up-napi-rs-canvas. I was able to make it work on a message as an attachment, but I couldn't when I tried to set it as `setImage` for an embed message.

I searched for topics about making it work with embed and ended up with the code below, which does not work. It's throwing an error on the `AttachmentBuilder` line.

> Failed to convert JavaScript value `Undefined` into rust type `String`

```js
const canvas = Canvas.createCanvas(700, 250);
const context = canvas.getContext('2d');
const background = await Canvas.loadImage('./myimage.png');
context.drawImage(background, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
const attach = new AttachmentBuilder(canvas.toBuffer(), {
  name: 'image.png',
});

const embed = new EmbedBuilder()
  .setAuthor({ name: 'KP', iconURL: avatar })
  .setDescription('Hello')
  .setColor('#F8C8DC')
  .setThumbnail(thumbnail)
  .setImage('attachment://image.png');
client.channels.cache.get(channelId).send({ embeds: [embed], files: [attach] });
```

**[UPDATE 1]**

The first suggestion about using `toDataURL` did not work:

```js
const canvas = Canvas.createCanvas(200, 200);
const context = canvas.getContext('2d');
context.fillStyle = 'red';
context.fillRect(0, 0, 200, 200);
const dataURL = canvas.toDataURL();

const embed = new EmbedBuilder()
  .setAuthor({ name: 'KP', iconURL: avatar })
  .setDescription('description..')
  .setColor('#F8C8DC')
  .setThumbnail(thumbnail)
  .setImage(dataURL);
client.channels.cache.get(myChannel).send({ embeds: [embed] });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `@napi-rs/canvas` the `canvas.toBuffer()` method [takes the MIME type](https://github.com/Brooooooklyn/canvas/blob/main/index.d.ts#L365) as a parameter. So you will need to use a type like `image/png`, `image/jpeg`, `image/webp`, or `image/avif`. In your case the following should work:

```js
const attach = new AttachmentBuilder(canvas.toBuffer('image/png'), {
  name: 'image.png',
});
```